# Conditionally add object to an array while being declared

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
  const arr = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      money: 45
    },
    {
      name: 'Lui',
      money: 65
    },
    {
      name: 'Kegan',
      money: 100
    },
    ... isNewUser  ? {
      name: 'Eric',
      money: 90
    } : {}
  ]
```

I need to conditionally add the object when it is declared not using `array.push`. Ive tried using the && operator but I just got errors.`isNewUser` is a boolean variable and if true, array should have 4 items, else the array should only have 3 which doesnt include the newUser object

Comment: Why do you **need** to do it during initialisation? What is is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I have a large codebase that contains arrays like this and I now I need to display data conditionally and adding array.push() after every declaration would cause more ugly code. Im trying to keep it as clean as possible

Comment: You have a different definition of "clean" then I do...

Comment: If it can be solved in one line using a spread operator than adding if(isNewUser) {...}  every time it is used would be mmuch simpler and less duplication

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only spread an array into an array. So simply make your conditional element an array.

```js
var arr = [{
        name: 'John',
        money: 45
    },
    {
        name: 'Lui',
        money: 65
    },
    {
        name: 'Kegan',
        money: 100
    },
    ...isNewUser ? [{
        name: 'Eric',
        money: 90
    }] : []
]
```

Anyways, `array.push` still looks like a better option here!

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      money: 45
    },
    {
      name: 'Lui',
      money: 65
    },
    {
      name: 'Kegan',
      money: 100
    },
   ]
 const newObj = {
      name: 'Eric',
      money: 90
    }

  if(newUser){
   arr = [...arr, newObj];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I like [Ajith Gopi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66892177/4174789) very much.

I would additionally use some helper functions.

```
function toArray(obj) {
  if (obj == null) {
    return []
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj
  }
  else {
    return [obj]
  }
}

function iif(condition, trueObj, falseObj) {
  return condition ? toArray(trueObj) : toArray(falseObj)
}

var arr = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    money: 45
  },
  {
    name: 'Lui',
    money: 65
  },
  {
    name: 'Kegan',
    money: 100
  },
  ...iif(isNewUser, {
    name: 'Eric',
    money: 90
  })
]
```